# How do I create a new line in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have appended a textbox to a div area. However I want it to goto a new line in that div after it does that, so my `for` loop prints a column of textboxes instead of a row.

I tried this:

```
<div id="timearea"> </div>
var br = '<br/>';
br.appendTo("#timearea");
```

However this does not work. What would the code be?

Comment: If this is jQuery it would likely be $("#timearea").append('<br/>')

Answer (score 4):

You would need to create the element using the `createElement()` method then append the child to the element using the `appendChild()` method

```
var br = document.createElement("br");
document.getElementById("timearea").appendChild(br);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you apply CSS styling to your divs to control how they are laid out. You can add attributes to style inline or (preferably) add classes to assign styles via JavaScript.

The [display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) attribute controls the flow - `display:block` should do it.

```
.my_block_class {
  display:block;
}
```

You can then add the class with JavaScript like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript):

```
document.getElementById("timearea").className += "my_block_class";
```

Or, if you want to do it without classes:

```
document.getElementById("timearea").style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean `textarea` or `input type="text"` but regardless, it is better to do this in CSS.  In your CSS file or inline style description add:

```
#timearea input {
  display:block;
}
```

If it's an `input` element you are adding, or:

```
#timearea textarea {
  display:block;
}
```

If it's a `textarea`.